# Explain more clear about str.rstrip()?

Tags: python

Why

```py
'mississippi'.rstrip('ipz')
```

return

```
mississ
```

I read https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip but not clear.

[image]

Comment: That function removes all of the i's, p's, and z's from the end of the string.  It's a set of characters, not a literal string.  The last character that is not one of those is the last `s`.

Comment: What do you think it should return instead? Why? "but not clear". The documentation says: "The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed". Do you understand what a set is, conceptually? If the code instead read `'mississippi'.rstrip({'i', 'p', 'z'})` (that will have the same result) would you find that easier to understand?

Comment: Thank all of you, I understand after comment from Tim Roberts.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it doesn't treat the argument as a prefix of suffix, but rather removes all occurrences of each character from the end.

If you read the docs for `str.strip` it explains the reason a little better.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip